# track changes on Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

How can I track changes to attributes or objects in Microsoft Active Directory? I'm looking to gather information on what user changed something, when they changed it, and what they changed.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the [built-in auditing tools](https://superuser.com/questions/477001/windows-driver-signing)?

If you're on Server 2008 or later, the **Directory Service Changes** auditing seems to be the one that you're most interested in.  Changes are logged to, I believe, the Security event log.